# managing lock on message in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, locking, zeromq

I'm trying to use RabbitMQ in a more unconventional way (though at this point i can pick any other message queue implementation if needed)

I have one queue (I can have more if needed) that where customers are fetching N messages asynchronous. After they do their work I send the results from the client to the db.

I have two problems: first I don't want that they will work on the same message, second I want to grantee that I wont lose messages in case that my customer will close the browser or just stop working.

I looked at the documentation and saw the TTL which was perfect for me if I could alter that message that got timeout isn't going to be deleted but to move to another queue. can't find a way to alter this.

Moreover I looked at the confirmation option which in the first glance looked what I wanted,that mechanism is working like this: when the consumer gets a message he send confirmation to queue, I thought I can delay this confirm and send it when the work is done on the client side.
my problem was that I can't program the queue that if any message didn't get confirm then return it to the queue (or to another).

I also find how to do a scheduled message but it didn't help either because I don't want that the message will be inserted to the queue in five min,I want that when a customer will receive a message it will be locked in the queue for 5 min until confirm to delete is set otherwise return it to the queue.

Can I do temporary queue that enables my mechanism?

If someone can help with one of the problems or suggest another architecture or option to do it in another MQ it would be great.

Resources:

confirmation:
http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2011/02/10/introducing-publisher-confirms/

post about locks but his problem was a batcher component:
[Locks and batch fetch messages with RabbitMq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985643/locks-and-batch-fetch-messages-with-rabbitmq)

TTL:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html

Schedule a message:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2015/04/16/scheduling-messages-with-rabbitmq/

Answer (score 0):

> my problem was that I can't program the queue that if any message
>   didnt get confirm then return it to the queue (or to another).

RabbitMQ does this anyhow, so all you have to do is switch off the auto-ack flag, you figured this out

> I thought I can delay this confirm and send it when the work is done
>   on the client side.

so just send the ACK once you've finished with processing the message.
All the unacknowledged messages remain in the queue and are re-delivered to next consumer (or the same one when it's up again, depending on your setup)